# how do I fix this error

Tags: unicode, characters

in this section latex says that there  is package inputenc:Unicode character×(U+7D). how should I fix this. this is the section of text where latex throws the error:

humans have tried to help mother nature many times, most of the time this has been a failure resulting in the destruction of delicate ecosystems. Humans have also ended up polluting ecosystems, introducing alien species into ecosystems. the biggest example of Introduction of a alien species is the snakehead, this fish was realised into a river into a river in California. soon these fish began to move out as the fish can breathe on land moving from river to river. with no natural predator the precious ecosystems have been destroyed but this does not mean humans are only causing damage. In Dubai a team relocated a large amount of corals from a busy harbour. Without the ten million dollar project the corals would have died and, in a world, first only 9 corals did not make it. Usually during relocation one in three corals would have died. In 2013 when it was finally opened to the public people saw a thriving coral reef that would have died if it wasn`t relocated. this is just one of the major examples that humans can help the environment. these events have become more and more common in a positive trend. pollution provides a cocktail of problems like the break down which takes dissolved oxygen out of the water.  this drop in the oxygen content will affect animals like penguins as the have a lower amount of prey. this combined with high concentrations of heavy metals is a recipe for disaster. this is combined with things like the longevity of chemicals makes thing worse. Duursma and Marchand (1974) reported an estimated world production of DDT about 2.8 × 106 tons of which 25 percent is released into the ocean. this was the state in 1974. a study for DDT and its breakdown products in the tails of rat fish in the arctic regions long after the ban on DDT.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Debugging questions require you to post code which does produce the error you're facing. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question. But from your error error code and text, I can tell that the problem is `×` which is not set up for LaTeX. You can use `$\times$` instead of that char.

Comment: A quick fix is to use `$\times$` instead of the `×`

Comment: Also consider using package `siunitx` to output your units with numbers, you could for example use `\usepackage{siunitx}\DeclareSIUnit\ton{t}` and then in your document `\SI[parse-numbers=false]{(A\times B)}{\ton}`. Also note that a ton seems to be not reliable usit (if you don't mean a metric ton) as its actual definition changes based on where you are.

Comment: And you have a doubled "into a river": "this fish was realised into a river into a river in California."

Comment: And you're missing a few upper casings after full stops.

Comment: And I think you meant "released" in the sentence with the doubled "into a river" instead of "realised".